# How can I find long reports?

Tags: abap

How can I find all reports that have more than 200 000 lines?
I have checked SCI and CODE_SCANNER, did not find anything like this there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could research the report RS_ABAP_SOURCE_SCAN and see how SAP searches in Reports. This way you can create your own ABAP report which searches for large reports.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first: Do you know the name of the reports? 
If not you first have to get a list of name for all objects that are in your interest. You could browse the table `TADIR` directly and search for the objects.

If you are looking for Reports only (and not for Function Modules and Classes)
you can use the internal commands `READ REPORT` or `LOAD REPORT`.

While SAP offers a lot of functions and methods for source codes they were, at least in older releases, not the most performant once.

But again with 7.4 a lot has improved.